# .htaccess 301 redirect sub domain query

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to 301 redirect this:

```
/blog/?=31
```

to

```
/blog/
```

and

```
/blog/?page_id=2
```

to

```
/blog/
```

I've tried the obvious stuff:

```
Redirect 301 /blog/?p=31 /blog/
Redirect 301 /blog/?page_id=2 /blog/
```

And obviously it didn't work otherwise I wouldn't ask this question here, so don't state the obvious!

Answer (score 1):

In order to handle redirects involving **Query Strings**, you will need to use a `mod_rewrite` `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}` in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^blog http://example.com/blog? [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: doesn't work for me. I've tried this by my self before and didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`Redirect` directive is provided [by **`mod_alias`**](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_alias#redirect). I'm not sure, but I think that it does not receive the query string parameter. Using `mod_rewrite` though, the rules would be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=31|page_id=2$
RewriteRule ^/?blog/?$ /blog/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: technically this should work. but it just does not work. I think the problem is the way my site is set up. under the main site we have a wp installation then in a directory under the main site is another wp installation. I'm not 100% sure where to place my redirect. Currently all my redirects for both root site and /blog/ site is located in the root .htaccess file.

Comment: @SchalkKeun If you are trying to redirect `http://whatever.com/blog/?p=31` to `http://whatever.com/blog/`, then the rules will go in root dir. Also, you'll need to check whether mod_rewrite is enabled or not.

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled 100% sure as the wp installation is using seo friendly url structure and my rewrite statements are enclosed in a `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c></IfModule>`, another thing is that the site is hosted on a AWS cloud server. Some more info inside the `<IfModule>` condition is a few `RedirectMatch` that are working 100%

Comment: `RedirectMatch` is again provided by `mod_alias`. To check if the rules are being processed, put the following just after `RewriteEngine` line: `RewriteRule ^ https://stackoverflow.com/`